# Copying and pasting boards in Trello

Tags: trello

I have regular projects that have the same components and I start a new project about once a month. The steps to complete these projects are the same from project to project.

Is there a way I can copy the structure of the project (lists) onto a new board? Or, copying a board and pasting onto a new board would work too.

I would love to be able to just start filling in and assigning tasks instead of typing in all the lists each time.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I checked it, and I can't find any way to move lists across boards, but you can move cards one-by-one between boards.

Trello has active development team you can request for it via [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would like to see our most-requested feature implemented: Copy/Clone/Template. You can vote it up here: https://trello.com/c/LIqasVwP

Answer (score 0):

You can create a board and name it as template. Then you can copy it via the Menu->More->Copy board. 
Note you will have to add the Members manually again, if I remember well, they are not copied.